# This Java Program is always printing only 10 but not printing SB.Why?

Tags: java, static-initialization

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Hello.a1);
    }
}

class Hello {
    static  final int a1=10;
    static {
        System.out.println("SB");
    }
}
```

This code is always printing 10 but not printing SB.Why?

Answer (score 10):

A `static final` field is implemented as a compile-time constant which is replicated in the accessing method/class without any reference to the context of definition (its class). This is why accessing it does not trigger the static class block.

This is basically due to the `final` keyword. If you remove `final` as follows:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Hello.a1);
  }
}
class Hello{
  static int a1=10;
  static{
    System.out.println("SB");
  }
}
```

You will see that `SB` is printed as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You are using static final constant variable. This variable will be replaced at the compile time by the actual constant value, in-order to increase the performance. If you have a look at the compiled binary code (Yes you cannot ;) but technically speaking with an assumption) it will be something similar to this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(10); // Constant
    }
}

class Hello {
    static  final int a1=10;
    static {
        System.out.println("SB");
    }
}
```

Based on this code, class Hello will not be loaded into the RAM. So it will not print the SB.

Answer (score -3):

Your static code block willbe invoked, when you create an instance of the class. Try this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        System.out.println(Hello.a1);
    }
}

class Hello {
    static final int a1 = 10;
    static {
        System.out.println("SB");
    }
}
```

Comment: static initialization block is invoked when the class is loaded into the memory. Instance initialization block is the one invoked, when you create an instance of the class.